Set default collapse of TreeChart nodes
I'm using the TreeChart component from @carbon/charts-react in my React application to display a hierarchical tree structure. The data for the tree is passed to the component via props, and it works perfectly fine with nested children.
However, as the data is becoming larger, I'm looking to optimize the user experience by collapsing the nodes by default. Specifically, I want the main parent nodes to be open initially, and upon clicking each node, its children should expand.
Here's how my component structure looks:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { TreeChart } from "@carbon/charts-react";
import options from "....";

const TreeComponent = (props) => {
  const { data,.... } = props;
  const updateOptions = { ...options};
  return (
    <div>
       <TreeChart data={data} options={updateOptions}></TreeChart>
    </div>
  )
};

TreeComponent.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  .....
};

export default TreeComponent;

Demo data:
{
    "name": "analytics",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "cluster",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
            "value": 3938
          },
          {
            "name": "CommunityStructure",
            "value": 3812
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "graph",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "BetweennessCentrality",
            "value": 3534
          },
          {
            "name": "LinkDistance",
            "value": 5731
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "optimization",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "AspectRatioBanker",
            "value": 7074
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "animate",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Easing",
        "value": 17010
      },
      {
        "name": "FunctionSequence",
        "value": 5842
      },
      {
        "name": "interpolate",
        "children": [
          {
          "name": "ArrayInterpolator",
          "value": 1983
          },
          {
            "name": "ColorInterpolator",
            "value": 2047
          },
          {
            "name": "DateInterpolator",
            "value": 1375
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

this is a sample data of props.data
At the initial stage only "analytics and animate" need to be in the dendrogram, when open "analytics or animate" it's first children need to show, but note that if it has a nested children the it also need to be collapsed until it is open.
